# Magento overrule Magento/Sales/Model/Order/ShipmentFactory.php

Tags: magento2

I trie to overrule Magento/Sales/Model/Order/ShipmentFactory.php and i have code below, but i get error:

```
main.CRITICAL: ReflectionException: Class "Jilco\Shipmentbug\Model\Order\ShipmentFactory" does not exist in /home/jilco/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:34
```

registration.php

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Jilco_Shipmentbug', __DIR__);
```

DI.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShipmentFactory" type="Jilco\Shipmentbug\Model\Order\ShipmentFactory" />
</config>
```

Module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Jilco_Shipmentbug" />
</config>
```

ShipmentFactory.php

```
<?php
namespace Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;

/**
* Factory class for @see \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentInterface
*
* @api
* @since 100.0.2
*/
class ShipmentFactory
{
/**
 * Order converter.
 *
 * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Convert\Order
 */
protected $converter;

/**
 * Shipment track factory.
 *
 * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\TrackFactory
 */
protected $trackFactory;
```

...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `module.xml`, replace

```
<module name="Jilco_Shipmentbug" />
```

with the following code to make your module load after `Magento_Sales` module.

```
<module name="Jilco_Shipmentbug">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
```

In `ShipmentFactory.php`, there are 2 places need to change:

1. replace

```
class ShipmentFactory
```

with the following code to allow your class to override `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShipmentFactory` class.

```
class ShipmentFactory extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShipmentFactory
```

2. replace

```
namespace Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
```

with

```
namespace Jilco\Shipmentbug\Model\Order;
```

Finally, run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` to re-sort order your module and Magento_Sales, and remove generated files (and cache):

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added wrong file path in preference di.xml file.

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment" type="Jilco\Shipmentbug\Model\Order\Shipment" />
```

You need to extend the parent file path which is like below and rename file name ShipmentFactory to Shipment because it makes confusion.

```
class Shipment extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment
```

You have added the wrong namespace in php file please update with this.

```
namespace Jilco\Shipmentbug\Model\Order;
```